# Change file extension, but keep original file

Tags: bash

I have a set of .txt files I want to change the extension of, but keeping the original.

I'm trying to cp each file to a "temp", then mv that "temp" to a new file with a new extension.

```sh
for file in $@; do
cp ${file} temp; mv temp ${file}.fas
done
```

I can't find out why it's not working, but nothing happens. I'm new to bash, so any help appreciated.

Comment: How are you calling your script? Is `$@` empty?

Comment: You should use `"${file}"` instead of `${file}` to handle file name with spaces.

Comment: Oh yes, that's right. When I use 'ls', I get the files in my directory as expected, by when I use "echo $@" it's empty. Any reason why?

Comment: @bactro `"$@"` gets the arguments passed to your script. If you use it interactively, you're not in a script, so there are no arguments. (Well, you can assign an argument list with `set`, but that'd be kind of weird.) Also, note the double-quotes: you almost always want double-quotes around variable and parameter references, because without them the shell parses the values in ways that tend to cause trouble. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out common mistakes like unquoted variable references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about [substring replacement in bash variables](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

This will copy all files like `foo.txt` to `foo.fas`:

```
for file in *.txt; do
    cp "$file" "${file/%.txt/.fas}"
done
```

Comment: Or `${file%.*}.fas`